# Connecting a polyfuse (PTC / resettable fuse) without soldering

Tags: soldering, protection, polyfuse

I want to connect up a polyfuse to protect a potentially flammable USB cable and a Raspberry Pi Zero in the circuit below. However it seems that most Polyfuses are supposed to be soldered and I'd much rather avoid doing that.

[image]

Is there any way to hook up a Polyfuse without soldering it, specifically with regard to the circuit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a barrier terminal block and a leaded polyfuse.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Just put the polyfuse leads under the screws on one side and the wires on the other side. Shrink wrap or sleeving on the leads wouldn't hurt, and they should be trimmed so they are not excessively long.

[Here](https://roboslam.wordpress.com/instructions/) is a different type of terminal block that works the same and some components are shown.

[image]